# Applying css to IE10 and below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Am I correct in thinking that IE 10, 9, etc. no longer support conditional statements? Also is it the case that JQuery no longer supports the browser object above version 1.9?

I am trying to apply a css rule just for IE. When using a Google font on my website Chrome renders it at lets say `14px` and it looks fine, in IE it's equal to about `15px` even though the developer tools shows it being `14px`. If I knock it down to `13px` on IE it then looks the same size as Chrome.

What is the best way to add a class to IE10 and below that will work across all the IE versions?

Comment: I think it's generally better to not worry about 1px differences.

Comment: The problem is that the 1px difference is making the text overflow the menu bar.

Comment: All browsers have different settings for font rendering, 1px difference I believe is acceptable. I suggest to reconsider your margins/paddings to allow this font rendering difference. More info here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/24/a-closer-look-at-font-rendering/

Comment: Have you tried explicitly specifying `line-height`? This helped me with weird font rendering leading to overflowed content in OS X. Also, code sample and live fiddle may help us to solve your issue w/o using IE10-specific hacks.

Comment: A difference of 1px in *font size* is something that you may need to worry about, but I would primarily try to solve the basic problem. There is not much real information about it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of a stupid solution, but it works (for IE10 and up only):

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    // do your IE10 magic
}
```

Comment: How about IE9, 8, etc? This also matches IE 11, by the way.

Comment: "IE10-only" is a bit misleading, because your snippet also matches IE 11.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the job :)